# Defining bind for home-made monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have defined my own version of WriterT along with a function to unwrap it:

```
newtype WT w m a = WT (m a, w)

unWT :: (Monoid w, Monad m) => WT w m a -> (m a, w)
unWT (WT cmaw) = cmaw
```

Now I am trying to define the monad `(WT w m)`, without success:

```
instance (Monoid w, Monad m) => Monad (WT w m) where
  return x = WT (return x, mempty)
  wtwma >>= fawtwmb = WT $ let (ma, w1) = unWT wtwma
                               (mb, w2) = unWT $ do a <- ma
                                                    fawtwmb a
                           in (mb, mappend w1 w2)
```

Error is located in the do-expression, at the point where I try to extract `a` from `ma`:

```
Expected type: WT w m a, Actual type: m a
```

I have tried a few variations, always with similar outcome. I am unable to define `bind` for this monad.

My main question is: **if the monad is inside a couple, how do I extract its value?**

Comment: luqui explains the essence of the problem, but note also that the class context on your `unWT` function does nothing whatsoever useful.

Comment: @dfeuer - I'd disagree, but please elaborate, possibly in the form of an answer. I define such unwrappers/runners all the time rather than using record syntax.

Comment: If you delete the class context from that function type, it will continue to work in all situations where it does now, but will also work in others. Under the hood, it takes two instance dictionary arguments which it then ignores completely. I'm not going to make that an answer because it's not the cause of your problem, which luqui resolves adequately.

Comment: Aah, I see what you mean! Thank you. I was just trying to be picky :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine the following computation:

```
tellLine :: WT String IO ()
tellLine = do
    input <- WT (getLine, "")
    WT (return (), input)

impossible :: String
impossible = snd (unWT tellLine)
```

If this works as "expected", we should get that `impossible` is the string that the user entered. However, we cannot do this outside of `IO`; such an `impossible` could not be a pure `String` as it is here.  So it is not possible to yield a `w` that was recieved as the result of a computation in the monad.

Another possibility is simply to return the `w` that occurred before the first bind, so we don't have to depend on any monadic actions.  Alas, one of the identity laws thwarts us.

```
return x >>= f = f x
```

Here we can see that "before the first bind" cannot be a meaningful concept, since there is a bind on the left but not on the right.  So returning the `w` that occurs before the first bind will surely violate this monad law.

The only remaining possibility is for the `w` to always be `mempty`.  But this does not work either, because of the other identity law.

```
m >>= return = m
```

so if `m` has a non-`mempty` value of `w`, the bind would annihilate it and violate this law.

This `WT` cannote be a monad transformer.  There is a `WriterT` transfomer, but it is defined as `m (a,w)` which avoids these problems.

Comment: What an eye opener! Thank you. Letting aside the fact that bind in this case is impossible, what would you say of the code I wrote to extract (mb,w2) by nesting a do-notation that deep? Is it allowed? Is it frowned upon? Could it be rewritten in a "better" way?

Comment: Stylistically it's fine. I would have used explicit bind operations probably, but I have seen others do this and don't think poorly of it.